# How can I find the memory footprint of a collection object in iOS / Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management, collections

I'm rolling my own object cache.  It's basically a NSMutableSet.

Is there a way to find out (programmatically) how much memory the collection is currently using, so that then I can trigger some purging of less important objects?

Comment: Just curious, any particular reason you're not just using `NSCache`?

Comment: hehe it occurred to me after I asked myself this question, and now I'm just curious.

Comment: Size should not be the only heuristic for purging objects from a cache. An object that is big and used a lot should stay in cache.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define "the collection". The size of the structure you use to maintain the collection? The size of the object pointers? The size of the instance variables that the objects hold?

You could purge data as needed on a memory warning.

The Objective-C runtime method to find out how much memory an object's instance variables uses is `class_getInstanceSize`, although I don't think this is the right approach. One object holding a single NSData with 5 MB of data will clock in lower than an object with two NSStrings.

Since I don't know why you're rolling your own cache, here's what I would do. I would define a method to work out a proportional cost to the items that I keep. (For an image, let's say width * height.) I would then use `NSCache` which supports supplying a cost with each object, keeping a maximum cost and purging automatically.

Comment: In the end I guess NSCache is the way to go?  Regarding the implementation of that, instead of a NSMutableSet or whatever, I just have to support the NSPurgeableContent protocol and treat the NSCache similarly to an NSMutableDictionary?

Comment: Yes, that's basically it. Also make sure, if you want to take advantage of the cost, to set the object and the cost.

Comment: I'm a little unclear about an object's 'cost'.  Is that a way of treating it like 'priority / importance' or is it a general measure of how large the object is?  what role does cost play in determining whether it be evicted or not?

Comment: Cost is a way of saying "this is how much, relatively speaking, this thing 'weighs'" (or in some cases how burdensome it is to recalculate). `NSCache` has a cost limit that you can configure and can start evicting items when all the items in the cache exceed that limit. There is a reason `NSCache` doesn't provide the cost for you when you add items to the cache; it can't. It's up to you to define this cost and how much of it is too much, but `NSCache` will do the rest for you when you have.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is nothing built in to address this problem. The `class_getInstanceSize`, `sizeof`, and `malloc_size` do not provide reliable approaches, because they would give you the size of an empty object or even an object pointer. This means that the size of a ten-character string and the size of a hundred-character string would measure the same if you take any of these approaches.

You can get a better approximation of the in-memory size of an object by checking its serialized size, but the objects inside your collection need to conform to `NSCoding` in order for this to work. You can make an implementation of `NSCoder` that calculates the total size of data that has been passed to it for serialization, without serializing the data "for real". Pass this coder to your collection's `encodeWithCoder:` method, then harvest the total size of all objects in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

sizeof() is a handy tool.

```
sizeof(object);
```

or

```
malloc_size(object);
```

Comment: Except that it will always return 32 bit or 64 bit (depending on the architecture) for any object, as they're all just pointers.

Comment: It returns the same result for a string as for an NSData object with 5 MB of data, so it may be more handy than universally useful.